# Get lookup field with xslt

Tags: sharepoint-designer, xslt

I have the following code in XSLT and I get the Id of "Evaluacion" lookup field with @EvaluacionIDLookup. I need to get the name of "Evaluacion" but the internal name is "EvalCompeEvaluacion" and if I set @EvalCompeEvaluacion intead I get a strange code.

```
</td><td class="ms-vb styleLine">
                <xsl:value-of select="@EmpleadoCargoLookup" /></td><td class="ms-vb styleLine" style="text-align:center; width: 90px;height:22px;">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="@RespuestaJSON != ''">
                        <a>
                            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                                <xsl:text>#</xsl:text>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
                                <xsl:text>javascript:EC.Empleados.ForEvaluation.ViewReport(</xsl:text>
                                <xsl:value-of select="translate(translate(@EmpleadoCedulaLookup,'.',''),',','')"/>,
                                <xsl:value-of select="translate(translate(@EvaluacionIDLookup,'.',''),',','')"/>
                                <xsl:text>);return false;</xsl:text>                        
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <img src='/_layouts/images/DATASET_SP16.gif' alt='Ver reporte de evaluación' style="border-style: none"/>
                        </a>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:text></xsl:text>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </td>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As lookup column/field is stored as id value pair in sharepoint so you could try to use

```
<xsl:value-of select="@LookUpField" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

It is worth trying although using a combination of `substring-before` and `substring-after` function like this.First step is to remove the hyperlink around the Lookup column then extract values from there-

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before("&le;/a&gt;", substring-after("*&quot;&gt;", @LookUpField))" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

Comment: I try with EvalCompeEvaluacion but It does not work

Comment: what is your actual lookup column name?

Comment: It is the first in the image. Display name "Evaluación" and the internal name is  "EvalCompeEvaluacion" but if I put @EvalCompeEvaluacion It does not work

Comment: In the code that I posted I have @EvaluacionIDLookup that is the las field in the image but I need "Evaluación"

Comment: Tried `<xsl:value-of select="@Evaluación" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>`  ?? Also now I suspect `ó` character.